# Mouswheel scrolling disabled since picture-slider was added

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been stumbling over something very strange when adding a picture slider to my page. Suddenly I was unable to scroll the page with the mousewheel, scrolling with the arrows worked though.

I've recreated a bit of the page on [codepen](http://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/eWYwoa/) but there it works without problems. Now I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong in my js-files.

The two scripts are loaded in the head-part of my html-code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/picture-slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/sticky.js"></script>
```

Here's the code from the slider:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentIndex = 0,
         items = $('.pictures_container div'),
         itemAmt = items.length;

    function cycleItems() {
        var item = $('.pictures_container div').eq(currentIndex);
        items.hide();
        item.show();
    }

    var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
        currentIndex += 1;
        if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
        cycleItems();
    }, 4000);

    $('.next').click(function() {
        clearInterval(autoSlide);
        currentIndex += 1;
        if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }
        cycleItems();
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
        clearInterval(autoSlide);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        if (currentIndex < 0) {
            currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
        }
        cycleItems();
    });
}
```

Is there another way of initializing the slider without using $(document).ready()? May this be the source of my problem? I've tried leaving it out, but the code wouldn't run without it. $(window).ready() resulted in the same problem as stated above.

I have tried finding a solution to this problem but most people wanted to disable the scrolling contrary to me willing to find a way to re-enable it (whatever disabled it in the first place...). One solution I've found though which stated that somewhere an overflow: auto was needed. But the only element that has an overflow-property is the .pictures_container which is needed so that the pictures won't fill the whole page.

I found the code for the slider on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp) but I had to change it a bit to have the pictures in a flexbox, aligned and justified centered and in full window-width.

In the CSS on codepen I have marked a section with the comment /* Content specific */ where the css-styles for the pictures-slider are in.

Am I right that it shouldn't matter whether the images are loaded from a folder or from URL?

I am really puzzled about the fact that it works just as intended on codepen. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Today I realized, that it does not always disable the mouse-wheel-scrolling, especially when I restart the browser (which btw is Chrome). But I still can't tell why it's being disabled or why it wouldn't work in the first place.

Comment: Does the page scroll bar appear in the non-working site?

Comment: Whats the code for sticky.js?

Comment: @SamJones the code for sticky.js is in the prepared codepen the last part under my comment about sticky.js

Comment: @RandyHall yes it does, but I'm not sure whether it was greyed out as I don't have it in front of me at the moment.